# How can i print specific fields, and get last word from last field that contain delimiter in each line

Tags: shell, awk

This maybe simple, but with lack of my programming skill, i can't figure it how to accomplish this.

I have content of **file.txt** like this :

```
1 22 July 2003 Path /Documents/Photo
2 23 July 2003 Path /Documents/Photo
3 24 July 2003 Path /Documents/Photo
```

and i only want to print field 2,3,4 and last word from last field that contain separator '/' each line.

like this :

```
22 July 2003 Photo
23 July 2003 Photo
24 July 2003 Photo
```

i've tried this with awk command, but its delete all word from last field.

`awk '{ print $2,$3,$4,$(NF=$NF) }'`

```
Lynx:~ root# cat file.txt | awk '{ print $2,$3,$4,$(NF=$NF) }'
22 July 2003
23 July 2003
24 July 2003
```

how can i accomplish this with awk,sed or grep?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: i have tried that, it delete all fields before '/' and i only got last word from last field. if theres any other suggestions? i will appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Please run `cat -v file` on your file and see if you have any control M characters in it?

Comment: Thank you! for your suggestions i will try that.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the last field on `/` and get the last item from the array

```
awk '{ 
i = split($NF,a,"/")
print $2,$3,$4,a[i] 
}' file
```

Output

```
22 July 2003 Photo
23 July 2003 Photo
24 July 2003 Photo
```

You could also remove all until the last occurence of `/` in the last field.

```
awk '{ 
sub(/.*\//, "", $NF)
print $2,$3,$4,$NF
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Simply setting field separator to space OR / here and printing 2nd, 3rd, 4th and last field's values for each lines.

```
awk -F'[ /]' '{print $2,$3,$4,$NF}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

another one

```
$ awk '{print $2,$3,$4,a[split($NF,a,"/")]}' file
```

or

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*\//,"",$NF); print $2,$3,$4,$NF}'
```

Comment: Ah, that short way of writing split is because split returns the number of items, and then you can index into a again right? ++

Comment: I love this short way, this also work as well, Thank you so much!